# Insert query not working as expected in Hive

Tags: hive

I'm using below query to insert data in hive.

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLE dc_financials_sales (salessourcenbr,
                    salessourcecountrycode, salesendinginvsalesdate,
                    itemdeptnbr, basedivcode,
                    childctrtrackingid, msgreceivedts,
                    finreportinggroupcode, gateoutuserid,
                    itemshippedqty, itemshippedqtyuom,
                    itemupc, outboundchanneltype,
                    parentctrtrackingid, salespolinenbr,
                    salesponbr, salesdocid, salesdocumenttype,
                    totalsalescost, totalsalescostuom,
                    trailergateoutts, trailernbr,
                    transportationloadid, saptransactionid,
                    vnpkqtyineaches, whpkqtyineaches,
                    whpksellcost, whpksellcostuom,
                    wmtitemnbr, wmtitemdesc)
VALUES (6086, 'US',
        '20191115', 7,
        'WM', NULL,
        '2019-11-21 09:04:06+0000', 'US',
        's0k01wf', 1,
        'EA', '28914173184',
        'Staplestock', NULL,
        NULL, NULL,
        '1168337034A', 'CO',
        100, 'USD',
        '2019-11-15 13:39:38+0000', NULL,
        NULL, '20191121090405332000000v7bG3NGSALEUS6086',
        1, 1,
        100, 'USD',
        '570495975', 'DISNEY PRINCESS ROYA');
```

But, getting error:

```
Your query has the following error(s):

Error while compiling statement: FAILED: 
SemanticException 1:38 '[salessourcenbr, salessourcecountrycode, salesendinginvsalesdate]' in insert schema specification are not found among regular columns of default.dc_financials_sales nor dynamic partition columns. 
Error encountered near token 'wmtitemdesc'
```

Can someone help me to understand why the query is not working in Hive?

Comment: Can you also add table definition of `dc_financials_sales` to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Hive does not support specifying ordinary (non-partition) columns in `INSERT VALUES` statement. See [Hive Language Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingvaluesintotablesfromSQL):

> ...Values must be provided for every column in the table. **The
>   standard SQL syntax that allows the user to insert values into only
>   some columns is not yet supported.** To mimic the standard SQL, nulls
>   can be provided for columns the user does not wish to assign a value to.